# Storm Armor and Diamond Skin?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I note that in each of the Armor skills in the Conjuration tree, it says that only one armor skill can be active at a time. Does Diamond Skin count as an Armor spell? Or can I trigger both Diamond Skin and, say Energy Armor or Ice Armor, at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Diamond Skin is classified as an *absorption effect*, so you can use an armour effect like Storm Armour along with Diamond Skin with no problems at all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can trigger Diamond Skin and "X" Armor at the same time.